Scary movie from the late 90s/early 2000s, 2 young girl ghosts, a tall man, and Thomas Edison ghost box
I remember seeing a scary movie on TV a bunch of times but can't remember the title. I remember this family moves into a new home near some woods. Their young son starts drawing on the walls of two little girls stick figures and and a red tall man stick figure leaning over them. 
There's another scene when a "ghost box" is used, it's introduced as being made my Thomas Edison and acts like an EVP recorder and is used multiple times. 
The other scene I remember is one where the young son is playing with the dad's office toy- it's a box with pins and used to make impressions. The boy sets it down and walks away, the girls' ghost voices giggle in the back ground and their stick figure faces appear as an impression (this was part of the trailer too I think). I remember really liking it and being creep-ed out by it. Any help is appreciated. 

Nightworld: Lost Souls (1998)

Victor Robinson has just moved into a country home with his family. When his son, Jesse, finds an old Edison invention and begins to play it, he hears the sounds of children laughing and playing. This is followed by Victor's autistic 12-year-old daughter, Meaghan, painting and singing; this is surrounded by strange occurrences around the house. When Victor discovers that two children were murdered in the area years before, he believes they are trying to contact him; he also believes that their neighbor is responsible for the murders.

If you go to 2:39 you can see the drawing with the red tall man:



